# Swift UITableView Weekdays - opening and closing hours

Tags: swift, uitableview

As in title, I’m looking for a solution to my application consisting in add opening and closing hours to the weekdays.

Image myApp:

[View list days of the week](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIPCL.png)

[View after selecting the day of the week, (View add hours)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfguc.png)

Code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class OpeningHoursInfoController: UITableViewController, AddDayHouerControllerDelegate {

    let daysOfWeek = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]
    var keyCell = "celllllId"
    var hoursArray = [HourInfo]()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        fetchOpenAndCloseHour()

        tableView.separatorStyle = .singleLine
        tableView.separatorColor = .lightGold
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
        tableView.register(OpeningHoursInfoCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: keyCell)
    }

    private func fetchOpenAndCloseHour() {

        let context = CoreDataManager.shared.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<HourInfo>(entityName: "HourInfo")

        do {

            let hours = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)

            hours.forEach({ (houers) in

            })

            self.hoursArray = hours
            self.tableView.reloadData()

        } catch let fetchErr {
            print("Failed to fetch error in CoreData:", fetchErr)
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 60
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return daysOfWeek.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: keyCell, for: indexPath) as! OpeningHoursInfoCell

        let days = daysOfWeek[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = days
        cell.textLabel?.textColor = .white

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let day = self.daysOfWeek[indexPath.row]
        let addDayHouersController = AddDayHouerController()
        addDayHouersController.delegate = self
        addDayHouersController.navigationItem.title = day
        navigationController?.pushViewController(addDayHouersController, animated: true)
    }

    // MARK: - AddDayHouerControllerDelegate Methods

    func didAddHour(hour: HourInfo) {

        hoursArray.append(hour)
        let row = hoursArray.index(of: hour)
        let reloadIndexPath = IndexPath(row: row!, section: 0)
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [reloadIndexPath], with: .middle)
    }


}
```

Code AddDayHouerController:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

protocol AddDayHouerControllerDelegate {
    func didAddHour(hour: HourInfo)
}

class AddDayHouerController: UIViewController {

    var delegate: AddDayHouerControllerDelegate?

    // MARK: - Widok
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Przycisk NavBar
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Save", style: .plain, t
    }

    @objc func handleSave() {

        let context = CoreDataManager.shared.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let hourInfo = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "HourInfo", into: context)

        hourInfo.setValue(hourFrom, forKey: "openHour")
        hourInfo.setValue(hourTo, forKey: "closeHour")

        do {
            try context.save()

            dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
                self.delegate?.didAddHour(hour: hourInfo as! HourInfo)
            })

        } catch let errSave {
            print("Failed to save CoreData:", errSave)
        }

    }

    // Picker View Target
    @objc func handleAddHour(button: UIButton) {

        view.layoutIfNeeded()
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {

            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

        }) { (completed) in

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {

                self.timePickerView.alpha = 1
                self.timePickerView.tag = button.tag
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            })
        }
    }

    let timePickerView: UIDatePicker = {
        let pv = UIDatePicker()
        pv.timeZone = .current
        pv.datePickerMode = .time
        pv.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleChoiceTime), for: .valueChanged)
        return pv
    }()

    var hourFrom = ""
    var hourTo = ""
    @objc func handleChoiceTime(sender: UIDatePicker) {

        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.timeStyle = .short
        let selectedTime = formatter.string(from: sender.date)

        if timePickerView.tag == 0 {
            openFromTimeButton.setTitle(selectedTime, for: .normal)
            hourFrom = selectedTime
            print(hourFrom)
        } else {
            openToTimeButton.setTitle(selectedTime, for: .normal)
            hourTo = selectedTime
            print(hourTo)
        }

        timePickerView.alpha = 0
    }
    }()


    }

} // End class
```

How to achieve this effect?
(For example - "Monday: 9:00 AM - 5:00 PM")

Comment: What does the code in `AddDayHouerController()` look like?

Comment: I'm sorry, I've already added. As for the code, I added the most important parts. Class AddDayHourController: Selected hours are saved in CoreData. Additionally I tried to send a delegate to the class with the List of Days of the week. The effect was that each day of the week has the same hour.

Comment: How are you fetching the data from core data in `UITableViewController`?

Comment: I have updated the code again. In the class "OpeningHoursInfoController" I created the "fetchOpenAndCloseHour" function fetch our data from CoreData. However, I still did not know how to add to the appropriate row.

Answer (score 0):

You need an appropriate data model, for example a class to get reference semantics

```
class DayOfWeek {
    let name : String 
    var openHour : Date?
    var closeHour : Date?

    init(name : String) {
         self.name = name
    }
}
```

Then create your data source array

```
let daysOfWeek = [DayOfWeek(name:"Monday"), 
                  DayOfWeek(name:"Tuesday"), 
                  DayOfWeek(name:"Wednesday"), 
                  DayOfWeek(name:"Thursday"), 
                  DayOfWeek(name:"Friday"), 
                  DayOfWeek(name:"Saturday"), 
                  DayOfWeek(name:"Sunday")]
```

instead of `hoursArray` use the `Date` properties in the class or declare the class

```
class DayOfWeek {
    let name : String 
    var hourInfo : HourInfo?

    init(name : String) {
         self.name = name
    }
}
```

---

In `cellForRow` assign the `name`

```
    let currentDay = daysOfWeek[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = currentDay.name
```

When presenting `AddDayHouerController` pass the instance at the corresponding index path to the controller and set the hours. Due to reference semantics (this instance and the instance in the data source array points to the same object) you don't need to pass the changed item back.

---

Note: Why do you register `OpeningHoursInfoCell`? If the cell is designed in the table view in Interface Builder and you are not using an extra XIB you **must not** register the cell.

Comment: Thank you for a quick reply.  I registered AddDayHouerController because I had previously used the class to which I called let daysOfWeek and I display the custom label in class OpeningHoursInfoCell.

Comment: As for the code, I did as you wrote. The list of days is shown correctly. However, I don't know how to do it in the class AddDayHouerController. Because I assigned the date values to the new class DaysOfWeek I received an error:  “Cannot assign of type ‘UIButton to type ‘Date?’ “ My time Open and Close is two buttons that after changing the date the changes .setTitle(selectedTime) Do I need to replace the button with the label? Unless I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: You have to create a property of `var dayOfWeek : DayOfWeek!` in the `AddDay..` controller and assign `day` in `didSelect` to that property right before presenting the controller. Please learn how to pass data between controllers, it's a very frequently used pattern.

Comment: And I don't know how you could assign a button to the `Date` property. The date properties are examples how to include the hours in the model. It could be also the `NSManagedObject` instance.

Comment: I managed to pass the selected day. 
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let day = daysOfWeek[indexPath.row]
        let addDayHouersController = AddDayHouerController()
        addDayHouersController.delegate = self
        addDayHouersController.dayOfWeek = day
        navigationController?.pushViewController(addDayHouersController, animated: true)
    }
I also changed the selected dates in the button to show on the labels.